# Subset original data and spatial data

Tags: r, filter, criteria, spatial

I have created a spatial points data frame (df_sp$Latitude) and would like to plot a graph comparing against variables in my original data frame (df$Abundance).

However, I would like to filter all values that are greater than zero from df$abundance. How would I filter these out, and the corresponding variable within df_sp$latitude, without ending up with this error that I am currently getting?

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

I'm able to generate a simple plot like this:

`plot(df_sp$Latitude, df$Abundance)`

However, I'm unsure as to how to subset my data to include abundance values greater than zero.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that generated that error?

Comment: Usually I use dplyr to subset my data, such as this `m1 <- dplyr::filter(df, Abundance > 0)`. So I tried entering `df_sp$Latitude` in various ways, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't see how  df_sp$Latitude could possibly be a spatial points data frame. To have a point you would need two coordinates. You also need to settle on a spelling for "latitude".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 <- cbind(df_sp$Latitude, df$Abundance)
df2 <- df2[df2$Abundance > 0,:]
plot(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, you should bind the x and y together, so you will filter them at the same time. Otherwise you will have different length arguments. Then you can plot as before. At this point you just plot the resulting matrix with two rows, r will place the first column as the x coordinate and the second column as the y coordinate. The below code accomplishes this:

```
plot(cbind(df_sp$Latitude, df$Abundance)[df2$Abundance > 0,])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, you're exactly right, this is what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, yeh I only needed to cbind the two data sets, and  filter them afterwards